# Loading Excel row with data using ListObject

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to load rows in an Excel worksheet, "List of Golfers", from worksheet "Players". On the Players worksheet I have a table named "GolfTrip". On the table I have columns named LastName, FirstName and Yes_No.

My code sets the objPlayers and cycles through each row in GolfTrip determining who is a "Yes".

I want to load the variables LName and FName with the current row. Once loaded I would like to put the values of LName and FName to column A starting on row A5 in "List of Golfers" worksheet.

```vb
Sub getPlayersCommitted()

    Dim objPlayers As ListObject
    Dim YN As Range
    Dim LName As String
    Dim FName As String
    Dim cnt As Integer
    
    cnt = 0
                  
    Set objPlayers = Sheets("Players").ListObjects("GolfTrip")
    
    For Each YN In objPlayers.ListColumns("Yes_No").DataBodyRange
        Select Case YN.Value
            Case "Yes"
                cnt = cnt + 1

                'Below I was attempting to load LastName and FirstName fields from the current row equalling Yes from the GolfTrip table.
                'LName = objPlayers.ListColumns("LastName").DataBodyRange
                'FName = objPlayers.ListColumns("FirstName").DataBodyRange
                
                'Then want to add LName, FName to column A on worksheet List of Golfers starting on row A5 within worksheet List of Golfers.
                                                    
        End Select
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Count of Players: " & cnt
    cnt = 0
    
End Sub
```

Sample data from GolfTrip table.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can read the row values:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim rw As ListRow, lo As ListObject
    Dim LName As String
    Dim FName As String
    
    Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("GolfTrip")
    For Each rw In lo.ListRows
        If rw.Range.Cells(lo.ListColumns("Yes_No").Index).Value = "Yes" Then

            LName = rw.Range.Cells(lo.ListColumns("LastName").Index).Value
            FName = rw.Range.Cells(lo.ListColumns("FirstName").Index).Value
            
            Debug.Print LName, FName
        
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```